# IOS App Flow After Pressing A Button

Tags: ios

Suppose there is button on first screen of an app which is connecting to second screen(i.e on click on that button second screen will come) and also to a function on first screen class .
Now my question is what is the flow first function||second screen  will executes?or both simultaneously will execute.

Comment: Try it out! Set breakpoints on your function, and viewDidLoad on the second view controller and see how they get triggered.

Comment: It depends on which specific functions you call. You should post your code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know that iOS Applications usually use MVC pattern.

So for your example, you have the View (V), containing the design, your button etc..

And the Controller (C), implementing the logic.

The answer is : You can decide which one comes first, just depends how you implement it.

But I don't really understand the logic in your example, can you be more specific.

You should try to make 1 interface element for 1 purpose.